# pass address of arr[0][2] , that must be received in a double pointer

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, pointer-to-pointer

need a better approach to pass address arr[0][2], given that is has to be received in a double pointer.

want to pass arr[0][2] without storing in any other variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int help(int **arr)
{
    cout<<**arr;
}

int main()
{
    {
    int n=3,m=3,k=0;
    int **arr = new int*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[m];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            arr[i][j]=k;
            k++;
        }
    }

    int *g=*arr+2;
    int **h=&g;

    help(h);

}
}
```

Comment: why do you "need" to pass a `int **` ? And what is "better"?

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: please read tag descriptions before using them. The one for `double-pointer` tells you that you shuold not use it

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? It's a bit confusing, and a bit long-winded, but it's correct. There is no way to get a double pointer without using some intermediate variable, if that's your concern.

Comment: Likely this requirement comes from an exercise the OP has been given to test their understanding of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way. Unfortunately C++ syntax `x[y]` can be used to mean two very different operations: if `x` is an array then is indexing, if `x` is a pointer they it's indirection and indexing.

If a caller expects a pointer to a pointer and you've a bidimensional matrix there's nothing you can do except actually creating the pointer that is not present in the matrix and pass its address.

The fact that with an array of pointers, with a pointer to a pointer and with a 2d array the syntax to reach an element is `x[y][z]` is irrelevant... they are three very different operations.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write

```
int *p = &arr[0][2];

help( &p );
```

If you want to get an access to the whole array using a pointer of the type int ** then you can use the following approach.

```
#include <iostream>

void help(int **arr, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << ( *arr )[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    int arr[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>( arr );

    help( &p, 6 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```